# The findOrCreate method has not been setup

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have created the custom user with base User and i am searching the following email exist in db or not , if email exist then don't create it and log the access token .

```
module.exports = function (User) {
  let app = require('../../server/server');
  var loopback = require('loopback');

  var credentials = { email: 'foo@foo.com', password: 'password' };
    var filter = {
        'where': {
            'email': credentials.email
        }
    };
    loopback.User.findOrCreate(filter, credentials, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;

            User.login(credentials, function (err, token) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(token);
                process.exit();
            });

    });

Error:

Error: Cannot call User.findOrCreate(). The findOrCreate method has not been setup. The PersistedModel has not been correctly attached to a DataSource!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your Datasource configuration and see if it's properly connected to the Database.

Answer (score 0):

Just try by

```
User.findOrCreate(filter, credentials, function (err) { });
```

As in Loopback doc

```
PersistedModel.findOrCreate([filter], data, callback)
```

Reference Link : https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-findorcreate